# The refresh token isn't being sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, oauth-2.0, google-api, omniauth

I'm using a gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'

```
#initializers/omniauth.rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider(:google_oauth2, 'client_id', 'client_secret') 
end
```

And then

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def google_oauth2    
    @user = User.find_for_google_oauth2(request.env['omniauth.auth'], current_user)
    #...
```

And then I get this

```
request.env['omniauth.auth'][:credentials]
=> {"token"=> "some token", "expires_at"=>1421821319, "expires"=>true}
```

I wonder, where is the refresh token? According to the documentation

> access_type: Defaults to offline, so a refresh token is sent to be
>   used when the user is not present at the browser. Can be set to
>   online.

But it's not sent, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are referring to the omniauth-google-oauth2 README by documentation. It also says that "if you need a refresh token, google requires you to also to specify the option prompt: 'consent', which is not a default". So try passing prompt option to the provider method.

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider(:google_oauth2, 'client_id', 'client_secret', { prompt: 'consent' })
end
```

Comment: where does it say that?

Comment: At the explanation of access_type in https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2#configuration